# Akka: How to convert tuples to bytestring?

Tags: scala, akka

How is it possible in Akka to convert a `Tuple2[a:A,b:B]` to `ByteString` for serializing data in this way `connection ! Write(ByteString(data))` and deserialize it back on the other side?

Comment: Do you want to serialize / deserialize the tuple? What is the purpose of the conversion?

Comment: `ByteString(tuple.toString)` <-- this will do it, but your question needs more info into what you are trying to accomplish. There are lots of ways to go from a tuple to a `ByteString`. Picking an approach depends heavily on whether or not you want to also be able to easily go back from `ByteString` to a tuple.

Comment: I have updated the question

Comment: You could consider using Pickling to serialize to / deserialize from JSON: https://github.com/scala/pickling

Comment: Akka has serialization built-in. You can even override with your own serializer. Check this out: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.8/scala/serialization.html

Comment: Still it is not clear to me how to deserialize a sequence of bytes to a tuple2 of generic type.

Comment: I've been using kryo (twitter chill) for this, and it works very well